# paperclip upload picture

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, pic

## Here is my need:

I have three prize, each prize has one pic, like:

prize1   pic1
prize2   pic2
prize3   pic3

## Here is my design:

I use four record in my database,  row 1 to 3 is mappingt to prize1 to prize3, and row4 is a default prize which can be used as adding prize.

## Here comes the question:

When is user paperclip to upload my pic, there's some problem to identify each pic. Details are following:

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="pic[]">
<input type="file" name="pic[]">
<input type="file" name="pic[]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I choose `choose file` to upload and submit the form, `pic` array will be passed by params, so I can get the the pic, and save them by the ordering of array.

However, when I only `choose file` for one prize, the array's size will be 1, and I couldn't judge which one has changed in the backend, so I'd like to hear from all of you, let me have a look at how you design it or could I make some changes to solve it!

## Tanks any way

Comment: What have you tried? No one here will take an answer starting with "do my [blank]work for me"

Comment: @hd1 I have solved the problem by myself, I use js, and set 
<input type="hidden">  to save img value, and then compare it in 
controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make sure that the photo upload is the correct resource that is updating the prize that you are wanting.

Assuming that each prize in your database has its own row and paperclip column set up correctly you will want the form to be like this:

```
= form_for @prize, method: 'put', html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.file 'pic'
  = f.submit
```

This should `PUT` the the picture information to the `/prize/1234` and the controller should consider the photo fields/params as attributes and update accordingly.

Things to watch out for:

1. Don't forget to add multi-part
2. Make sure that paperclip is configured properly
3. Make sure that other attributed in thr form for the product can be updated as well

Good luck!

Comment: thx for you nice answer, my configuration is right, and I just use js
to solve the problem